# em-websocket and javascript client connection

Tags: websocket, eventmachine, em-websocket

I've got a simple eventmachine web socket server (eventmachine 1.0.0):

```
EM.run {

  # WebSocket Server
  EM::WebSocket.start(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|
    ws.onopen do
      sid = @channel.subscribe{|msg| ws.send msg }
      puts "* new WebSocket client <#{sid}> connected!"
    end

    ws.onmessage do |msg|
      puts "* websocket client <#{@sid}> : #{msg}"
    end

    ws.onclose do
      @channel.unsubscribe(sid)
      puts "* websocket client <#{@sid}> closed"
    end
  end
}
```

I'm trying to connect to it through a javascript client with the following code:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
  socket.send('Connesso');
};

socket.onmessage = function(mess) {
  if (mess) {
    socket.send(mess);
  }
};

socket.onclose = function(e) {
  socket.send('Disconnesso');
};
```

With previous versions of safari it was working flawlessly with the latest one the client is not connecting to the server.

I tried it also with last Chrome Dev stable version but it's not working.

The web socket header is sent but it remains in pending status.

If I send a text message to the web socket I receive the `INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11`.

I saw that there has been a draft change but I thought em-websocket 0.3.8 already implemented it.

Can you help me solve this issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 means your websocket is not in ready state yet.

you can check state of websocket object by socket.readyState
you are able to send messages when socket.readyState == 1

I created a turnaround for this by using timeout

```
timerId = setInterval(sendDataWhenReady, 1000);
function sendDataWhenReady(){
  if(socket.readyState == 1){
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({"type": 'STATUS', "status": status, "username": logged_in_user}))
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your correct explanation but my problem is the websocket is not going in ready state

Comment: that means when you are trying to send some data over the websocket connection, it is not ready at that time
try sending that data using javascript console of browser, it will not  raise the error :)